# Why are my questions being closed?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to go into trouble again, so why are my questions being closed? Are they too simple?

Comment: Previous question it seems was a subject (about regexp) why..

Comment: Could I reason further?

Comment: I didn't see the question, but if it was about regexp, was it just regexp? or a specific tool, e.g. `sed`? regexp alone is probably more of a stackoverflow. regexp for sed, or vim, or grep, etc, would match here more.

Comment: The problem with the regexp question was that after rereading it multiple times, I still didn't know what it was asking. That is the reason I flagged it for moderator review.

Comment: what is stackoverflow?

Comment: who can share knowledge with general questions . Why stack? What overflows, .. pour of water (like pour of questions). Can I admire service or will be punished for any emotion? Again why there (name is not saying anything).

Answer (score 8):

This is well-covered in the site FAQ. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#close

---

In more specific:

- many of your questions are short and confusing, like [/opt/nvidia-smi from nvidia-drivers pack outputs "failed to load nvidia kernel module"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55647/opt-nvidia-smi-from-nvidia-drivers-pack-outputs-failed-to-load-nvidia-kernel-m) (When did you get that error? What did you expect to happen instead? What have you tried? What are the details of your OS and driver versions?)
- others are "list all the things", like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55265/commands-with-regex-support

The former can be improved, but the latter are out of scope for this site.

Comment: Mb it's mine IMHO, those restrictions don't look like as constructive ones, but rather authoritive.

Comment: Click the "How to Ask" link in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Some reasons I can see:

- [List of packages with regular expression support in flags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55472/15630) and
  [Commands with regex support?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55265/15630): open-ended (there could be thousands of packages and commands with regex support) and too localized (packages and commands could change at any moment and render the answers obsolete). 
  List questions aren't well suited for the Stack Exchange model: they become rapidly obsolete.
- [Who can use cron? I can't help myself. Who is using cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55290/15630): does not show what you have attempted.
- [All Unicode font coverage for Gentoo Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55169/15630): not a real question, and your edits make the question quite confusing (you don't need to say 'done'; you could just summarize and add an answer like "I found  in ").